# Is putting a string literal in executeQuery prone to an SQL injection in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've been looking around and can't seem to find a solid answer to this. I was wondering if putting a string literal in `executeQuery()` is still prone to SQL injection.

So lets say I have this code:

```
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","password");
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

  ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from users where uid = "+uid);
```

Is this prone to a SQL injection?

Another question is, is just making the method that uses this code only throw an SQLException, and then trying and catching in main acceptable?

For example:

```
public void execMethod(String uid) throws SQLException {
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","password");
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

      ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from users where uid = "+uid);
    // execute some other code
    res.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        execMethod("123");
        execMethod("456");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is this the standard or correct way of using SQL exceptions? I've never really worked with SQL and especially not Java and SQL. The tutorials I've read seem to only lay it out one way, so I'm pretty unsure of myself.

Comment: *"Is this prone to a SQL injection?"* - Yes, you have no control over what `uid` actually contains. *"Another question is, is just making the method that uses this code only throw an SQLException, and then trying and catching in main acceptable?"* Yes and no, you should at least wrap the contends of `execMethod` in `try-finally` to ensure that you are closing the resources you open (or use a `try-with-resources` for Java 7)

Comment: You should only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this prone to a SQL injection?"

Yes, you have no control over what `uid` might actually contain.

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

> Another question is, is just making the method that uses this code only throw an SQLException, and then trying and catching in main acceptable?"

Yes, but you should at least wrap the contends of `execMethod` in `try-finally` to ensure that you are closing the resources you open (or use a `try-with-resources` for Java 7)

```
public void execMethod(String uid) throws SQLException {

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "password")) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from users where uid = ?")) {
            stmt.setString(1, uid);
            try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                // Process ressult set
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

But, I would only catch the `SQLException` for EACH call, not batch them together, as you won't know what failed and what succeeded

```
try {
    execMethod("123");
    try {
        execMethod("456");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Maybe undo 123
        System.out.println("Failed 456");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Failed 123");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

(assuming that 456 is dependent on the success of 123)

Comment: I've always heard that even doing a couple of try / catch statements will seriously slow down the program. Is that something I should be worried about in this case?

Comment: Personally, I've not heard this, but you would need to take into consideration based on needs.  If you only processing small number of queries or have a reasonable delay between queries, what's the harm, when you gain the knowledge in what succeeded and what failed - but you've have to balance based on the context of the problem you are having.

Comment: And `try-with-resource` can be chained, for example `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "password"); PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from users where uid = ?")) {`, but I compounded it to make it more readable

Comment: try is practically free.  It's the throw that's expensive.  See this other SO post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451777/is-it-expensive-to-use-try-catch-blocks-even-if-an-exception-is-never-thrown

Comment: @MadProgrammer Normally you could chain the `try-with-resources` but in this case you need to bind the `uid`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch *face plant* Thanks forgot about that, updated the comment, least get rid of one level

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry did the comment update? It looks the same for me

Comment: @Alex Yes, I took out `ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()` (from my comment about compound `try-with-resources`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Awesome. Thank you for all of the advice and help :) I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : yes.

You do not appear to be doing any kind of input validation so there isn't anything stopping `uid` from being something like "105 or 1=1"

You should probably use `PreparedStatement`s [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from users where uid = ?")
stmt.setString(1, uid);

..same as before
```

Also you don't close the statement or the connection which should be done in a finally block incase an exception is thrown

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If `uid` can be entered by a user (it's not a `String` literal). I suggest you use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), and a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
final String sql = "SELECT * from users where uid = ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, uid);
    try (ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (res.next()) {
             // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `PreparedStatement` (with bind variable) has at least these advantages

1. It can use the `Statement` cache on the server
2. It is not prone to SQL Injection

Comment: While the "If `uid` can be entered by a user" is true, I think it's an assumption that should never be made if possible. It may be the case that a value isn't currently entered by a user, but it is in the future so leaving things as they are is just a vulnerability waiting to happen.