# How to check if object and nested fields are null

Tags: java, variables, object, field

I have an object and i want to check if this object or nested fields are null. I want to print this neted field, but i should check if there is null in some level, otherwise i will get null pointer exception .

I know i can do this:

```
if( object != null && object.A != null && object.A.B != null && object.A.B.C != null && object.A.B.C.D != null) { doSomething( object.A.B.C.D);}
```

but its so long. Do you know better way to check  it ?

Comment: You could try inserting nested fields into an array and then running a null-check for every object in the array, but I think it's too complicated to actually consider doing. But it's a possibility.

Comment: Prevent them from being null. Use the NullObject pattern / paradigm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Java or what Axel sais vvv

Comment: Well, if this is a complex nested data, what about doing a check at the end of this and catching the NPE, if an exception occurs, it is not valid. Using an exception is not a good idea but in some "exception", I would guess this is the easier

Comment: You could switch to [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org) and do `if (object?.A?.B?.C?.D) { doSomething( object.A.B.C.D);}`

Comment: After all, having to go down 4 indirections is a code smell ...

Answer (score 15):

Optional is a good way in Java 8.

```
String value = foo.getBar().getBaz().toString();
```

With optional it will be:

```
String value = Optional.ofNullable(foo)
                       .map(Foo::getBar)
                       .map(Bar::getBaz)
                       .map(Baz::toString)
                       .orElse("EmptyString");
```

Comment: Anyone know how the speed of this compares to if/else?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an interface on all objects with method that returns all child objects and create a method that calls itself recursively to verify that all objects are set.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that this is a check to prevent misuse of a method, so this should not occurs too many time.

Simply catch this exception, this will invalidate the value.

```
private boolean isValid(YourObject object){
    try{
         return object.A.B.C.D != null;
    } catch (NullPointerException npe){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, don't use this solution if you are doing a lot of validation and those return false to often, exception are an heavy process.

EDIT :

As Fildor point it out, there is a cost to use a try-catch even without exception. But using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451908/4391450) I can assume this will be limited and there is not much optimization to do on this unique line.

Comment: But the exception is not only expensive when it occurs. The existence of try/catch alone triggers costs already.

Comment: Mmmmh, that could change a lot then @Fildor. Is it that expensive ? See the edit and the link, this should be acceptable if this idea is really needed.

Comment: Not *that* much. I just wanted to point it out. So if this validation is done *very* often, it could be more efficient to find a solution that does not need it. But I agree that this would have to be taken into account if and when it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you to point that out. It is good to know. I agree that this is not the best solution but this had to be said ;)