# Regex pattern for mm/dd/yyyy and mmddyyyy in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have `date` in my `.txt` file which comes like either of the below:

```
mmddyyyy
```

**OR**

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

Below is the regex which works fine for `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
^02\/(?:[01]\d|2\d)\/(?:19|20)(?:0[048]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:0[13578]|10|12)\/(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}|(?:0[469]|11)\/(?:[0-2]\d|30)\/(?:19|20)\d{2}|02\/(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-8])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}$
```

However, unable to build the regex for `mmddyyyy`. I just want to understand is there any generic regex that would work for both cases?

Answer (score 2):

Why use regex for this? Seems like a case of ["Now you have two problems"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

It would be more effective (and easier to understand) to use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (assuming you are on the JVM and not using scala-js)

The format patterns support using `[]` to surround optional sections, such as the `/`, and the formatters inherently perform input validation so if you plug in a month or day that can't exist, it'll throw an exception.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

val mdy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM[/]dd[/]yyyy")
def parse(rawDate: String) = LocalDate.parse(rawDate, mdy)
```

```
scala> parse("12252022")
res7: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-12-25

scala> parse("12/25/2022")
res8: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-12-25

scala> parse("25/12/2022")
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '25/12/2022' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 25

scala> parse("abc123")
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'abc123' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: it will be more efficient to first check on `/` symbol. `Try` (actually, `throw Exception`) is a simple, but not an efficient way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451908/5122436

Comment: @MikhailIonkin I've updated the answer to take advantage of optional sections in the formatter pattern, so it no longer needs to use `try` or `Try`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all those variations with either 2 forward slashes or only digits, you can use a positive lookahead to assert either only digits or 2 forward slashes surrounded by digits.

Then in the pattern itself you can make matching the `/` optional.

Note that you don't have to escape the `\/`

```
^(?=\d+(?:/\d+/\d+)?$)(?:02/?(?:[01]\d|2\d)/?(?:19|20)(?:0[048]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:0[13578]|10|12)/?(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])/?(?:19|20)\d{2}|(?:0[469]|11)/?(?:[0-2]\d|30)/?(?:19|20)\d{2}|02/?(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-8])\?(?:19|20)\d{2})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4DVFv9/1)

Another option is to write an alternation `|` matching the same pattern without the `/` in it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a tiny shortcoming in your regex: the `^` anchor only applies to the first part of your regex, not to the other alternatives that are separated by `|`. Similarly the final `$` applies only to the final alternative. You should put all alternatives in a non-capturing group, like  `^(?:  |  |  |  )$`

Then for the question itself, you could make the forward slash that follows the month optional and put it in a capture group. Then what comes between the day and the year could be a backreference to that capture group. So `(\/?)` and `\1`.

```
^(?:02(\/?)(?:[01]\d|2\d)\1(?:19|20)(?:0[048]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:0[13578]|10|12)(\/?)(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])\2(?:19|20)\d{2}|(?:0[469]|11)(\/?)(?:[0-2]\d|30)\3(?:19|20)\d{2}|02(\/?)(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-8])\4(?:19|20)\d{2})$
```